# How to create class object depending on one statement

Tags: java

I have trouble with creating class objects.
I have two classes, Employee and Article. Both of them have same methods(edit(), remove(), save(), list()). Now I want to create object "obj" from the specific class, depending on the string "item", so I can use him later like showed bellow.

**My method**

```
    private void subMenu(String item) {

        switch(item) {
            case "employee":
                Employee obj = new Employee();
                break;
            case "article":
                Article obj = new Article();
                break;
        }
        obj.edit();
        obj.remove();
        ...
    }
```

I tried something like this but it just throws Exception:

```
 Duplicate local variable obj
```

**Class Article**

```
public class Article() {

    public void edit() {

    }

    public void remove() {

    }

    public void save() {

    }

    public void list() {

    }
}
```

**Class Employee**

```
public class Employee() {

    public void edit() {

    }

    public void remove() {

    }

    public void save() {

    }

    public void list() {

    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid casting your objects you'll need to use either an interface or an abstract class that defines those methods that both of your classes implement/extend

Comment: You should get Employee and Article to extend a common interface which has the required methods.

Comment: I have add interface and extend both classes with it. And so what now, have the same error. Even if i change from 

    Employee obj = new Employee(); to Item obj = new Employee();

Comment: Declare local variable outside of switch statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Create an interface with all common methods (give it a better name than `Item`):

```
public interface Item {

    void edit();

    void remove();

    void save();

    void list();
}
```

2) Make *both* classes implement that interface:

```
public class Article implements Item {

    public void edit() {

    }

    public void remove() {

    }

    public void save() {

    }

    public void list() {

    }
}
```

3) Replace local variables with `Item`:

```
private void subMenu(String item) {
    Item obj;
    switch(item) {
        case "employee":
            obj = new Employee();
            break;
        case "article":
            obj = new Article();
            break;
       default:
            return; //FIXME Can it happen?
    }
    obj.edit();
    obj.remove();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create an interface with that methods:

```
public interface InterfaceName {
    void edit();
    void remove();
    void save();
    void list();
}
```

and implement it to Article and Employee classes

```
public class Employee implements InterfaceName {
  ....
}

public class Article implements InterfaceName {
  ....
}
```

Now you can use the interface in your method

```
private void subMenu(String item) {
    InterfaceName obj;

    switch(item) {
        case "employee":
            obj = new Employee();
            break;
        case "article":
            obj = new Article();
            break;
    }
    obj.edit();
    obj.remove();
    ...
}
```